# React Native with multiple Navigations

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a home screen that consists of around 20 different pressable icons(news, photos, hobbies....) where every item leads to a different screen.

```
<Stack.Navigator>
   <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={screen1}/>
   <Stack.Screen name="News" component={screen2}/>
   <Stack.Screen name="hobbies" component={screen3}/>
   .
   .
   20 more


</Stack.Navigator>
```

In the future, I might add more items, leading to a different screen. I can add as many as navigations in my home to navigate to all the screens. But is it a good practice to create these many screens in my app.js file?. The other problem is I might have nested screens on some of the screens. Example:
Hobbies Screen contains edit, add, delete etc. on Click of add I am redirecting to a new form screen that has multiple fields. Same with an update. I might have screens like this

```
A
B
 a
 b
 c
C
D
 a
 b
 c
 d
E
.
.
.
```

I end up creating multiple screens like this

```
<Stack.Navigator>
   <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={screen1}/>
   <Stack.Screen name="News" component={screen2}/>
   <Stack.Screen name="hobbies" component={screen3}/>
   <Stack.Screen name="hobbiesedit" component={screen4}/>
   <Stack.Screen name="hobbiesupdate" component={screen5}/>
   <Stack.Screen name="hobbiesdelete" component={screen6}/>
   .
   .
   more


</Stack.Navigator>
```

I don't think this is the better approach to follow(keeping in mind I may add more screens). Are there any other optimal approaches to achieve the goal?

Comment: you must use tab navigator for the main screens which must remain there always and use stack navigator for the screens that pop ups from the single screen. this will make it easier to debug and also separation between mainScreens and subScreens for more information read this doc [navigation layout](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/combining-stack-navigator-with-tab-navigator-in-react-native-react-navigation-253656f45181)

Answer (score 0):

regarding the having this much screens in app.js I would recommend creating multiple different navigation files in a navigation folder, where one of the files contains all the screens and stacks and navigator, the other has the container of the first file so something like this :

```
<NavigationContainer>
<FirstNavigationFile />
</NavigationContainer>
```

and lastly in your app.js you can import it and make as your main render.
as for the second part of your question, I wouldn't do it like that, I would make stacks for each set for example (picture, add picture, modify picture) is a stack inside the home stack.

I hope I was clear and I helped you.